# Python - How to sort strings with numbers inside of them in a list

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort the highscores of my game in order from highest to lowest but I also want the name next to it so it is still a string.

This is my list

```
highscores = ["Herbert 99999", "Bob 543", "Jerry 35", "Fred 325", "Tom 972"]
```

How do I sort these in order so I can print them out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the high score at the start of your list then:

```
highscores = ["Herbert 99999", "Bob 543", "Jerry 35", "Fred 325", "Tom 972"]
highscores.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), reverse=True)
print(highscores)
```

**Output:**

```
['Herbert 99999', 'Tom 972', 'Bob 543', 'Fred 325', 'Jerry 35']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a key function that, for each string, returns a tuple of the form `(score_as_integer, name_as_string)`. That way, ties will be sorted by name.

```
def by_score(item):
   name, score = item.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
   return -int(score), name.lower()

highscores.sort(key=by_score)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be a lot better off using a dictionary

```
highscores = {"Herbert": 99999, "Bob": 534, "Jerry":35}
```

Then you could just sort the dictionary by the values

```
dict(sorted(highscores.items(), key =lambda highscore: highscore[1], reverse=True))
```

Using a dictionary would also probably make your code more efficient.
I hope this helps, apologies if it doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

```
highscores = ["Herbert 99999", "Bob 543", "Jerry 35", "Fred 325", "Tom 972"]

# temporary list of ordered pairs
tmp = sorted(map(str.split, highscores), key=lambda pair: int(pair[1]), reverse=True)

# marge each pair to get a list of strings
ordered_highscores = list(map(' '.join, tmp))

print(ordered_highscores)
```

Output

```
['Herbert 99999', 'Tom 972', 'Bob 543', 'Fred 325', 'Jerry 35']
```

Answer (score 1):

highscores.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split()[-1]))

gives

['Jerry 35', 'Fred 325', 'Bob 543', 'Tom 972', 'Herbert 99999']

Quite neat

Comment: This is perfect but how do I get them to be order from highest to lowest so herbert is the first score

Comment: @fdsafas Take a look at the documentation for *sort()* and, in particular, the *reverse* keyword

Comment: You can also just negate the value retuned in the function